# Odd text output at prompt using fish-shell

Tags: shell, ubuntu, configuration-files, fish

#### The Problem

I have an odd problem with Fish Shell on my Ubuntu 13.10 laptop.  I've been using Fish for a few months now with 100% default settings.  Last night everything seemed fine, but this morning I noticed something when I opened a new terminal.  Every time I hit a key on the keyboard, the text `write to 5` is output to the console.  See the screenshot below for an example of what happened when I typed `ls` and `pwd` commands at the prompt.

#### My Questions

How do I go about finding the source of this odd text?  Is it a fish config file?  A fish function that got redefined by mistake?

#### More Clues

- I first noticed this behavior after opening a new fish shell this morning.
- Another shell I had left open from last night did not have the problem.
- All new fish shells have the problem.
- I do **not** see the problem if I start a bash shell inside an existing fish shell.
- Rebooting my laptop did not help.
- I am overwhelmed by the fish documentation.

#### Screenshot

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using nightly builds? This was a debugging line that made it into a nightly, and should have been fixed the following day.

The bug tracking this is https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1413

Comment: Ah!  Thanks so much!  Yes I am using the nightly build.  At the time I set this up I thought it would be great to stay up to date with the latest and greatest.  And that's exactly what I got!  Thanks again.